# stuck on a github build

Tags: clone, github

i would like to install this github program. 
https://github.com/ChrisLuck/ut71dmm

made directory (in home) ut71dmm
unzipped the downloaded github .zip file into that directory
tried to followed the readme from there.

- cd into ut71dmm
- clone hidapi: git clone git://github.com/signal11/hidapi.git
  but tgot the following error msg: No command 'clone' found

also tried:

- git clone hidapi: git clone git://github.com/signal11/hidapi.git
  error: to many arguments.

and

- git clone git://github.com/signal11/hidapi.git
  seemed to work.. at first.
  Cloning into 'hidapi'...
  remote: Counting objects: 2006, done.
  remote: Total 2006 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 2006
  Receiving objects: 100% (2006/2006), 2.72 MiB | 425.00 KiB/s, done.
  Resolving deltas: 100% (1174/1174), done.

but upon make: i got the following error msg:

- gcc -I./hidapi/hidapi -Wall -g -c `pkg-config libusb-1.0 --cflags` hidapi/libusb/hid.c -o hidapi/libusb/hid.o
  Package libusb-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libusb-1.0.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libusb-1.0' found
  hidapi/libusb/hid.c:47:20: fatal error: libusb.h: No such file or directory
  include libusb.h>

i understand i messed up.. there :(

and would really appreciate some support to get this up and running..

Kind regards

Matthieu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the `libusb-1.0-0` development package.
You can install the package using the `apt-get` package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

needed an additional dependency:

```
# for a additional missing libudev dependent library. 
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev
```

Comment: thank you for a quick response.  so i just did..  but:  clone hidapi: git clone git://github.com/signal11/hidapi.git still leaves the same error message: co command clone found.  and when i use make:  also the same:

Comment: gcc -I./hidapi/hidapi -Wall -g -c `pkg-config libusb-1.0 --cflags` hidapi/libusb/hid.c -o hidapi/libusb/hid.o
Package libusb-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libusb-1.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libusb-1.0' found
hidapi/libusb/hid.c:47:20: fatal error: libusb.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libusb.h>

Comment: which is strange..  additionally i would like to say that i believe i had libusb already installed in the past, just not sure if it was libusb or libusb-dev.

Comment: You would have installed the binary library files only not the header files for development activity.

Comment: but this time i definately did! just get stuck on the "No command 'clone' found" error.  i believe that to be the major issue.

Comment: You just need to run `git clone git://github.com/signal11/hidapi.git` not the whole line.

Comment: well thought that was the case.. just wasn't sure.  so i deleted the entire folder and did unzip again and now run that command again.  working as expected. but then again upon make i get that libusb-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search. but it did install libusb-dev as you said. 
sudo apt-get install libusb-dev: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 91 not upgraded.

Comment: just run the command `pkg-config libusb-1.0 --cflags` if you are getting the same error then the `pkg-config` file for the libusb package is missing from your system or pkg-config is not able to pick it up.

Comment: pkg-config libusb-1.0 --cflags
Package libusb-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libusb-1.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libusb-1.0' found
how do i find out if it is missing, or pkg-config isn't able to pick it up?  and how can i solve either?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63214/discussion-between-ameyavs-and-matthieu-kints-van).